# Rotate section headings

Tags: sectioning, rotating, sectsty

I'm trying to create a document according some brand guidelines which require the use of angled and coloured section headings.

I have the colours working using the `xcolor` and `sectsty` packages, but cannot find how to rotate the headings.

I've also tried using the `rotating` package. It works fine for ordinary text, but it throws an error when I try to use it for a section.

Here's my working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{my-green}{RGB}{134,162,11}

% Section Styling
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\huge \color{my-green}}

\begin{document}
    \section{I'd like to rotate this}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the answers below, here is the code I eventually used to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{scout-green}{RGB}{134,162,11}
    \definecolor{scout-purple}{RGB}{77,33,119}

\newif\ifwithrotation

\newcommand \basictitlebeforecode[1] {
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{\raggedright#1}
}

\newcommand \fulltitlebeforecode[1] {
    \ifwithrotation
        \rotatebox{6}{\basictitlebeforecode{#1}}
    \else
        \basictitlebeforecode{#1}
    \fi
}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]
        {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{scout-green}}
        {}{0em}
        {\fulltitlebeforecode{#1}}

    \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
        {\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries\color{scout-purple}}
        {}{0em}
        {\fulltitlebeforecode{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \section{Ordinary Short Section}
    \subsection{Ordinary Short Subsection}

    \withrotationtrue
        \section{Rotated Short Section}
        \subsection{Rotated Short Subsection}
    \withrotationfalse

    \section{This is a purposely long section title that extends on more than one line}
    \subsection{This is a purposely long subsection title that extends on more than one line}

    \withrotationtrue
        \section{This is a purposely long rotated section title that extends on more than one line}
        \subsection{This is a purposely long rotated subsection title that extends on more than one line}
    \withrotationfalse

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of the layout you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create some brochures and leaflets which follow the brand guidelines for UK Scouting: https://members.scouts.org.uk/comms_centre/zip/Brand_Guidelines.pdf The first page shows an example of the rotated text for headings

Comment: The simplest approach might be to use something like `\section*{\rotatebox{20}{1. I'd like to rotate this}}`.  (`rotatebox` is from the `graphicx` pacakge.)

Comment: @Thruston that works nicely! I may just use it in a newcommand

Comment: You'll be able to do that with the `titlesec` and the `graphicx` or `rotating` packages.

Comment: @Bernard Could you possibly show how that's done? I can't find it!

Comment: @Thruston you're assuming that there are no page headers or tables of contents I assume (putting formatting in the section argument is evil:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, the assumption is correct, but I'd still be interested in a less 'evil' solution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I was, but `\section[toc stuff]{\rotatebox{6}{rotated stuff}}` should also work.  But I agree it's a horrible kludge.  But then having sloping headings at all is pretty evil. In fact I'm not sure which I find more depressing: the fact that the Scouts feel the need for a 60 page branding manual; or the fact that it specifies a 6° slope for the headings...

Comment: @Thruston You should see the stuff that gets produced when people just do their own sweet thing! Colour combinations that induce an instant headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what can be done using `titlesec`and `graphicx`. See the documentation of titlesec, in particular for spacing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{my-green}{RGB}{134,162,11}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{my-green}}{}{0em}{\rotatebox{9}{\arabic{section}.\enspace\parbox[t]%
{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

  \section{This is a short title}
  This is a paragraph.

  \section{This is a purposely long title that extends on more than one line}
  This is a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes a rather more complete example than mine:-)

Comment: Not used titlesec before (never had the need for my own stuff), but this looks like the way to go. I should be able to define two section classes - with and without the rotation

Comment: @ Owen: Maybe you could introduce a boolean (`withrot`, say) and make the last argument a command that depends on the value of this boolean. It shouldn't be too hard with the `explicit`  option of titlesec. You also can create new sectioning levels.

Comment: @Bernard I managed to create two classes and get it all working. The boolean sounds better. I'll have to read up on how to do that. (Much more interesting than actually writing the content for this leaflet)!

Comment: @Bernard thanks again for the hint. Much nicer code now with a boolean variable and no need for a separate titleclass

Comment: @Owen: You're welcome. Let me add that I don't like so much creating new classes as it can have side effects on headers and toc.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The underlying `\@startsection` mechanism LaTeX uses for headings is designed to allow the
last command in the font specification to be a command that takes an argument, to allow rotation, uppercasing, etc. this facility falls through to the `secsty` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
    \definecolor{my-green}{RGB}{134,162,11}

% Section Styling
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\huge \color{my-green}\rotatebox{10}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

    \section{I'd like to rotate this}
    \section{I'd like to rotate this as well}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I get the 'egreg' bit, but that's an elegant solution to an inelegant problem!

Comment: Don't worry about that reference, I may remove it in a bit (just banter between the regulars here)

Comment: @Owen updated with a bit of explanation